# How to install and use python to work with python 2.7 in virtualenv?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, virtualenv

I seem to have multiple issues trying to install `ipython` in a virtual env, and work with python 2.7 in `ipython`.

First of all, I created a virtualenv and pip-installed `ipython`:

```
pip install ipython==1.2.1
```

So far, all looks good:

```
$ which python
~/Projects/BGLibPy/venv/bin/python
$ which ipython
~/Projects/BGLibPy/venv/bin/ipython
$ which pip
~/Projects/BGLibPy/venv/bin/pip
```

But the version of `ipython` does not match

```
$ ipython -V
0.13.2
```

and when I start `ipython` I see:

```
$ ipython
WARNING: Attempting to work in a virtualenv. If you encounter problems, please install IPython inside the virtualenv.
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Aug  9 2016, 06:11:56)
```

And yes, I did install `ipython` in a virtualenv. And why is the version of python 2.6 (inside `ipython`) but outside its 2.7?

```
$ python -V
Python 2.7.13
```

I am confused. What is going on, and how to fix this?

Comment: Your last output shows "Python 2.7.13" but your comment seem to suggest it would be "2.6". Any reason for using ipython over jupyter? Update: Okay, that is the version outside

Comment: Yes, I am remotely logged in to a compte (via another computer). Setup would be difficult, and I do not need any GUI

Comment: What is your */usr/bin/python* version? Maybe _ipython_ calls that explicitly. In cases like this, if a solution isn't quickly found, the best idea is to start from scratch.

Comment: Yes thats the 2.6.6 version. But starting from scratch would be very time consuming, as I already installed something completely else in that virtualenv...

Comment: I just checked; `IPython` should be also loaded correctly from inside the venv

Comment: I just have to do `python -m IPython` and it works as supposed to...

Comment: is the shebang of $VIRTUAL_ENV/bin/ipython pointing at the right python executable?

Comment: @jonatan: Yes the shebang of `ipython` is correct...

Comment: Would ipython really switch python version while it's running? I'd print out the python version from $VIRTUAL_ENV/bin/ipython , if it comes out as 2.7 but starts 2.6 then it switches and that's where the problem is, and if it comes out 2.6 then the shebang is wrong

Comment: fwiw when I install ipython 1.2.1 in a python 2.7.14 venv, the pid's in $VIRTUAL_ENV/bin/ipython and later in the interactive session match, it didn't spawn another process for executing commands in, so you probably started bin/ipython with the wrong interpreter which is decided by that shebang/the shell that reads that shebang

Comment: `ipython` shebang points to the venv python2.7 ...

Answer (score 0):

Workaround: Use

```
python -m IPython
```